# Userform for Dimensioning Parts Catia V5

Tags: vba, components, userform, dimension, catia

I'm a new VBA user and, so far, I've only used it for Excel databases.

Now, I'd like to use it in CATIA V5. For starters, I'd like to make a parameterized part whose dimensions can be modified in a userform. Is this possible?

So far, I believe it would go something like this:

- Name relevant sketch components
- Set constraints and whatnot in the drawing
- At any time, run macro to open userform
- Obtain user input values (in mm) for component dimensions of named components
- Set dimensions to user input values
- Update part

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible but if you are in Part Design workbench you should say features and not components. Components are used in Assembly Design workbench. I suggest you to start by using first a record of your "manually" actions in CATIA